# Is it possible to do mailing through the Telegram API in Java (Not a bot)

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

Suppose I have a channel in a telegram, I want to use the Telegram API to get a list of readers with their contacts and then do a newsletter for individual users. But it should not be a bot, because the bot cannot send messages first. I also wanted to implement an invitation to users using api. I looked through the documentation, but could not find examples of how the query should look like for each of the methods provided  in order to test the query through Postman(at least). Has anyone already done something similar, where can i get sample of queries? I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer : **You can't**

Telegram bots are very similar to humans so the question is : 
**"Can you do that manually?"**

Answer is : **of course you can't because you don't have access to their contacts.**

So all you can do is making a bot (ex : `@MyNewsletterBot`) and tell your subscribers click `/start` and get email address of your subscribers then send them email via another application or library in any other language or `Java`.